# 'Permission denied' when I cd into any folder

Tags: bash, permissions, directory, cd-command

Whenever I try `cd folder_name/` in bash on *any* directory it gives this error:

`-bash: cd: folder_name/: Permission denied`

Execution permissions are given to all folders so that doesn't seem to be the problem. E.g. running stat on `Desktop/` outputs:

```
  File: 'Desktop/'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 807h/2055d  Inode: 13107232    Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/caffeine)   Gid: ( 1000/caffeine)
Access: 2017-12-07 14:39:42.715820915 +0500
Modify: 2017-12-06 01:16:13.985722935 +0500
Change: 2017-12-06 01:16:13.985722935 +0500
 Birth: -
```

Some other possibly relevant information:

1. I can read or write files in any directory without any issue.
2. `mkdir` executes normally but I can't `cd` into the new folder.
3. `rmdir` executes normally.
4. I can open a terminal in a particular folder by navigating to that folder and opening a terminal from it.

So can anyone tell what the problem can be?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
`type -a cd` shows the following output:

```
cd is a function
cd () 
{ 
    echo "-bash: cd: $1: Permission denied"
}
cd is a shell builtin
```

Comment: Add the output of `type -a cd` to your post, please.

Comment: @muru Just did. That function wasn't supposed to show up wasn't it?

Comment: So, who do you know who would play a practical joke on you like that?

Comment: hahahahahaha, the friends we keep these days :-)

Comment: Run `unset cd` and things should work.  Next, run `grep 'Permission denied' ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile ~/.profile` and report what you find.

Comment: @John1024 That fixed it. Though the grep didn't return any results. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @AwaisChishti you will need to find where that `cd function` is set else it will repeat

Comment: Run that command for dir `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: Rechecked! The guy actually calls another script within .bashrc that does that.

Comment: The ones in /etc/ seem safe

Comment: Now add the output of `PS4=' ${BASH_SOURCE}:$LINENO: ' bash -lixc true |& grep Permission`, please.

Comment: @muru No output!

Comment: @AwaisChishti in that case, do `PS4=' ${BASH_SOURCE}:$LINENO: '; shopt -s extdebug; set -x; declare -F cd`

Comment: I retracted my close vote for the following reason: The OP uses 16.10, fine but this can happen on any Ubuntu version and I think other Users could benefit from this question to be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably where the victim of a prank, possibly done by your coworkers or someone who had access to your machine.

Bash functions can shadow the original shell built-in commands as you could see as you did `type -a cd`. It has shown you that it first found a function which is possibly declared somewhere.

```bash
cd is a function
cd () 
{ 
    echo "-bash: cd: $1: Permission denied"
}
cd is a shell builtin
```

From this output you can see that somewhere someone declared a shell function called `cd` which shadows now the shell built-in command `cd`. In some cases something like this might be useful to make commands more versatile or implement extra functionality, but in this case it was been done with ill intend (my guess). This could have been done in several places on the system:

- `/etc/bash.bashrc`
- `/etc/profile`
- any file in `/etc/profile.d/`
- `/etc/environment`
- `~/.bashrc`
- `~/.profile`
- `~/.bash_aliases`
- any other file which gets executed or sourced from those files

One possible way to find this maybe is doing a recursive `grep` search in `/etc/` and in `/home/`:

```bash
grep -r 'bash: cd: $1: Permission denied' /home/*
sudo grep -r 'bash: cd: $1: Permission denied' /etc/*
```

Which might yield an output like that:

```bash
$ grep -r 'bash: cd: $1: Permission denied' /home/*
/home/videonauth/.bashrc:    echo "-bash: cd: $1: Permission denied"
```

In this example the line or function seems to be in `~/.bashrc` which you can see by the path leading the `grep` output. Depending how sufficient the whole thing is hidden this might or might not yield a result. There are other ways to hide such a function declaration which may not be so easy to find.